# Add titles and caption above/below each tabular

Tags: tables

I am trying to create 4 tables as below: However I would like to add a title to each `tabular` and a caption below each `tabular`.

If you have any suggestion on how I can proceed it would be great.

```
\begin{table}
    \centering

    \begin{tabular}{@{}cc|cc@{}}

    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{} &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Predicted} \\ 
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{Yes} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{No} \\ 
    \cline{2-4}
    \multirow[c]{2}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=tr]{90}{Actual}}
    & Yes  & 100 & 0   \\[1.5ex]
    & No  & 10   & 80 \\ 
    \cline{2-4}
    \end{tabular}
    \quad% ---------------------------
    \begin{tabular}{@{}cc|cc@{}}
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{} &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Predicted} \\ 
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{Yes} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{No} \\ 
    \cline{2-4}
    \multirow[c]{2}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=tr]{90}{Actual}}
    & Yes  & 100 & 0   \\[1.5ex]
    & No  & 10   & 80 \\ 
    \cline{2-4}
    \end{tabular}

    \par\bigskip
    \begin{tabular}{@{}cc|cc@{}}
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{} &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Predicted} \\ 
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{Yes} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{No} \\ 
    \cline{2-4}
    \multirow[c]{2}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=tr]{90}{Actual}}
    & Yes  & 100 & 0   \\[1.5ex]
    & No  & 10   & 80 \\ 
    \cline{2-4}
    \end{tabular}
    \quad% ---------------------------
    \begin{tabular}{@{}cc|cc@{}}
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{} &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Predicted} \\ 
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{Yes} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{No} \\ 
    \cline{2-4}
    \multirow[c]{2}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=tr]{90}{Actual}}
    & Yes  & 100 & 0   \\[1.5ex]
    & No  & 10   & 80 \\ 
    \cline{2-4}
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set each `tabular` component inside a `minipage`. If the components within the `minipage` have differing heights, you can align them using `\begin{minipage}[<align>]{<len>}` (where `<align>` could be `t`op or `b`ottom).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multirow,graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering

  \begin{minipage}{.4\linewidth}
    \centering
    {\bfseries\strut Top left title}

    \begin{tabular}{@{}cc|cc@{}}
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{} &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Predicted} \\ 
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & 
      \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & 
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{Yes} & 
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{No} \\ 
      \cline{2-4}
      \multirow[c]{2}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=tr]{90}{Actual}}
      & Yes  & 100 & 0   \\[1.5ex]
      & No  & 10   & 80 \\ 
      \cline{2-4}
    \end{tabular}

    \caption{Top left caption}
  \end{minipage}%
  \quad % ----------------------------------
  \begin{minipage}{.4\linewidth}
    \centering
    {\bfseries\strut Top right title}

    \begin{tabular}{@{}cc|cc@{}}
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{} &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Predicted} \\ 
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & 
      \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & 
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{Yes} & 
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{No} \\ 
      \cline{2-4}
      \multirow[c]{2}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=tr]{90}{Actual}}
      & Yes  & 100 & 0   \\[1.5ex]
      & No  & 10   & 80 \\ 
      \cline{2-4}
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Top right caption}
  \end{minipage}

  \bigskip

  \begin{minipage}{.4\linewidth}
    \centering
    {\bfseries\strut Bottom left title}

    \begin{tabular}{@{}cc|cc@{}}
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{} &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Predicted} \\ 
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & 
      \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & 
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{Yes} & 
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{No} \\ 
      \cline{2-4}
      \multirow[c]{2}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=tr]{90}{Actual}}
      & Yes  & 100 & 0   \\[1.5ex]
      & No  & 10   & 80 \\ 
      \cline{2-4}
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Bottom left caption}
  \end{minipage}%
  \quad % ----------------------------------
  \begin{minipage}{.4\linewidth}
    \centering
    {\bfseries\strut Bottom right title}

    \begin{tabular}{@{}cc|cc@{}}
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{} &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Predicted} \\ 
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & 
      \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & 
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{Yes} & 
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{No} \\ 
      \cline{2-4}
      \multirow[c]{2}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=tr]{90}{Actual}}
      & Yes  & 100 & 0   \\[1.5ex]
      & No  & 10   & 80 \\ 
      \cline{2-4}
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Bottom right caption}
  \end{minipage}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

---

I enjoy the [`booktabs`](//ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) view a little better:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs,eqparbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering

  \begin{minipage}{.4\linewidth}
    \centering
    {\bfseries\strut Top left title}

    \begin{tabular}{ l c c }
      \toprule
      & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries Predicted} \\
      \cmidrule(lr){2-3}
      \bfseries Actual & \itshape Yes & \itshape No \\
      \midrule
      \itshape Yes & \eqmakebox[apval][r]{100} & \eqmakebox[apval][r]{  0} \\
      \itshape No  & \eqmakebox[apval][r]{ 10} & \eqmakebox[apval][r]{ 80} \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}

    \caption{Top left caption}
  \end{minipage}%
  \quad % ----------------------------------
  \begin{minipage}{.4\linewidth}
    \centering
    {\bfseries\strut Top right title}

    \begin{tabular}{ l c c }
      \toprule
      & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries Predicted} \\
      \cmidrule(lr){2-3}
      \bfseries Actual & \itshape Yes & \itshape No \\
      \midrule
      \itshape Yes & \eqmakebox[apval][r]{100} & \eqmakebox[apval][r]{  0} \\
      \itshape No  & \eqmakebox[apval][r]{ 10} & \eqmakebox[apval][r]{ 80} \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Top right caption}
  \end{minipage}

  \bigskip

  \begin{minipage}{.4\linewidth}
    \centering
    {\bfseries\strut Bottom left title}

    \begin{tabular}{ l c c }
      \toprule
      & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries Predicted} \\
      \cmidrule(lr){2-3}
      \bfseries Actual & \itshape Yes & \itshape No \\
      \midrule
      \itshape Yes & \eqmakebox[apval][r]{100} & \eqmakebox[apval][r]{  0} \\
      \itshape No  & \eqmakebox[apval][r]{ 10} & \eqmakebox[apval][r]{ 80} \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Bottom left caption}
  \end{minipage}%
  \quad % ----------------------------------
  \begin{minipage}{.4\linewidth}
    \centering
    {\bfseries\strut Bottom right title}

    \begin{tabular}{ l c c }
      \toprule
      & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries Predicted} \\
      \cmidrule(lr){2-3}
      \bfseries Actual & \itshape Yes & \itshape No \\
      \midrule
      \itshape Yes & \eqmakebox[apval][r]{100} & \eqmakebox[apval][r]{  0} \\
      \itshape No  & \eqmakebox[apval][r]{ 10} & \eqmakebox[apval][r]{ 80} \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Bottom right caption}
  \end{minipage}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[`eqparbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/eqparbox)'s `\eqmakebox` was just a quick horizontal alignment technique for `c`entred columns.

Comment: @user113156: You're welcome. I've added some `\strut`s to ensure a consistent vertical alignment and spacing between the `tabular` titles. You can see the difference in the [post revision history](https://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/456794/revisions).